Oracle SOA Invoke image
Is it possible to retrieve an image from a URL and return it to the user in Oracle SOA?
For example, consider this image URL:
https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/690/200/200.jpg?hmac=DN6slU20ktSeMSXbM6U8BG_YHhebxEl3S70qNurkzk8
I want to fetch the image from the URL and return it as is to the user.
